# How to correct a one or two letter typo on a Stack site, as the system requires me to edit at least 6 characters?

Tags: bug

I wanted to correct two typos in someone else's post. Together it was 2 characters. The system didn't let me submit it and required at least 6 characters to be edited. But the rest was OK and I don't want to mess in someone else's post unnecessary. I tried adding spaces but that didn't help. So I ended up canceling and leaving the typos in place. That's a pity and a waste of effort.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters

Answer (score 1):

As you gain [reputation](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) points on this site that editing limitation will go away. See also the [privilege](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) progression.